# C++11 not Working with Macports gcc47

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, macports

I recently installed Macports on my Macbook Pro, and installed the `gcc47` port. After adding `alias g++="g++-mp-4.7"` to my `.profile` and ensuring  that I was using `g++-4.7`, I attempted to build one of my projects that makes use of C++11. However, I receive this error:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
```

I find this strange, since Macports built gcc with support for C++, so I would expect that C++11 should work without any problems. I have pasted the output from `g++ -v` below. Do you have any ideas as to why `g++-mp-4.7` is not recognizing `-std=c++11` as a valid option?

```
COLLECT_GCC=g++-mp-4.7
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12/4.7.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12
Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.1/configure --prefix=/opt/local --build=x86_64-apple-darwin12 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,lto,fortran,java --libdir=/opt/local/lib/gcc47 --includedir=/opt/local/include/gcc47 --infodir=/opt/local/share/info --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --datarootdir=/opt/local/share/gcc-4.7 --with-libiconv-prefix=/opt/local --with-local-prefix=/opt/local --with-system-zlib --disable-nls --program-suffix=-mp-4.7 --with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/local/include/gcc47/c++/ --with-gmp=/opt/local --with-mpfr=/opt/local --with-mpc=/opt/local --with-ppl=/opt/local --with-cloog=/opt/local --enable-cloog-backend=isl --enable-stage1-checking --disable-multilib --enable-lto --with-as=/opt/local/bin/as --with-ld=/opt/local/bin/ld --with-ar=/opt/local/bin/ar --with-bugurl=https://trac.macports.org/newticket --disable-ppl-version-check --with-pkgversion='MacPorts gcc47 4.7.1_2'
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.1 (MacPorts gcc47 4.7.1_2)
```

Comment: i seen it here, maybe there is more information in the article. didnt read it... http://mlucassmith.tumblr.com/post/7785480841/time-to-play-with-c-11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For future reference, if you install gcc_select you can do:

```
 sudo port select gcc mp-gcc47
 hash gcc
```

This should setup your Macports installed gcc; if you need to reset to Xcode's default, just rerun it with 'none'

EDIT: and Xcode 4.4.x comes with a decent build of Clang; if you install it and then from Preferences->Downloads: Command Line Tools click "Install"

Run clang as:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ ...
```

Note that if mp-gcc47 is not installed, you'll need to do this first:

```
 sudo port install mp-gcc47
```

To get a full list of available gcc ports:

```
 sudo port list | grep gcc | less
```

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that since GNU Make executes commands in a different shell, `alias g++="g++-mp-4.7"` will have no effect on the commands executed by `make`.